# Interpretation of Symmetry Factor

Tags: quantum-field-theory

So on page 93 of Peskin and Schroder:
[image]
How would this work if I add an extra path, would it be $4!=24$ or $4\cdot2=8$?
[image]
Is it different permutation of the 4 path? Or is it 4 different way to reach $y$ from $x$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scalar fields (with a $\phi^{5}$ interaction*), the symmetry factor of the lower diagram is $4!=24$, because you can freely permute the four internal lines without changing the structure of the diagram.

*The $\phi^{5}$ interaction is needed because there are five legs attached to each interaction vertex of the diagram.

Comment: So is this the same for $\phi^4$ interaction? Thanks

Comment: @user278206 No, that diagram cannot occur in a plain $\phi^{4}$ theory, because it has vertices with *five* lines attached.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you!